# How to integrate Alfresco with Silverlight 4?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, alfresco

I want to integrate Alfresco with SL 4 app.
As Alfrsco provided restful services, it should be avaiable for SL 4 app.

Can anyone share a sample for this senario?

Answer (score 1):

You can access any web service that exposes a REST API using Silverlight. You should be able to add this as a Service Reference in your Silverlight project. [Here](http://christopherdeweese.com/blog2/post/using-silverlight-4-to-browse-netflixs-odata-catalog) is an article about how to access Netflix's OData API, which is REST-ish